# Are there Laravel Exceptions that we can manually throw in the application code?

Tags: laravel, exception, throw

I was wondering if Laravel has setup specific Exception classes for the developers to throw in their application code when needed. Is there such thing?

Comment: You can extend the exception handler to add your own  this might help you https://laraveltips.wordpress.com/category/handling-exceptions-and-custom-exceptions-laravel-5-1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some https://laravel.com/api/5.5/search.html?search=exception

But why would you want to throw them? You can create your own exceptions that will fit into your domain.

Comment: I am just checking my options ... nonetheless, creating my own exceptions seems to be the way since no standards are provided by Laravel.